# Save JSONObject

Tags: javascript, json, file

**what kind of object is this?** 
[image]
I am trying to craft mock data in order to test an application and this is how one of my fake data looks like. **How can I save this mock data?**

I could only thought of using the `JSON.stringify` function and copy the result to save as a string. Obviously, after I do that, I would have no access to the attribute of the original object.

[image]

Are there any ways I can **write this JSONObject into a file and have access to its properties later??**

Answer (score 0):

`JSON.stringify()` returns a string. To make an object you can access properties of again, you'll need to pass that string through `JSON.parse()`.

It's also worth noting that if the object you're saving has any functions in it, they will *not* be saved.

Comment: That is EXACTLY what I am trying to do. I am trying to save an object that have functions in it and I want to use these functions later.. Is this not doable at all?

Comment: If there're functions in the object, then hopefully it has a constructor you can call to make more instances. Check https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/constructor

Answer (score 0):

In your code `obj` is a javascript object

You can use blob (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob) and HTML5 download API to do the required as:

```
var json = JSON.stringify(obj);
var blob = new Blob([json], {type: "application/json"});
var url  = URL.createObjectURL(blob);

var a = document.createElement('a');
a.download    = "mydata.json";
a.href        = url;
a.textContent = "Download mydata.json";
```

You can load that data and access it properties later using and `XMLHttpRequest` GET request as:

```
function loadJSON(callback) {   

    var getobj = new XMLHttpRequest();
    getobj.overrideMimeType("application/json");
    getobj.open('GET', 'mydata.json', true); // Replace 'mydata' with the path to your file
    getobj.onreadystatechange = function () {
          if (getobj.readyState == 4 && getobj.status == "200") {
                // Required use of an anonymous callback as .open will NOT return a value but simply returns undefined in asynchronous mode
            callback(getobj.responseText);
          }
    };
    getobj.send(null);  
 }

 loadJSON(function(response) {
  // Parse JSON string into object
    var savedData = JSON.parse(response);
 });
```

Comment: I am very confused

Comment: Confused about what?

Comment: everything... i don't understand it at all

Comment: i am trying to save an object that has functions in it. will this do that? I dont get it

Comment: You should go through the blob link I posted. Also, you should read about GET request. The most efficient way to get data through an external file is GET request only. And yes, it will save all of that including functions in the file.

Comment: Functions will also be saved because they are properties of that object only. When you JSON stringify it, all of it will be converted to a stringified form and stored in the file. When you access it you need to use JSON parse to convert it to an accessible format

Answer (score 0):

Using local storage maybe.

```
   localStorage.setItem("MYMockData", JSON.stringify(fakeData));

   var fakeDataRetrived = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("MYMockData"));
```